# Javascript / CSS: Create custom CSS and wrap two Form Fields in red border when in Error

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, components, react-hooks

How do I create a new custom Border and use it to wrap these two components?

When the searchComponent is in error state (through front-end input field validation) I pass the error state to dropdown component, but the red Border it creates doesn't look the same surrounding the dropdown as it does on searchComponent. I am trying to get dropdown & searchComponent to be highlighted evenly in a red border if validation error.
[image]
HOOKS:

```
const [searchInputError, setSearchInputError] = useState(false);
const [searchInputErrorText, setSearchInputErrorText] = useState("");
```

COMPONENTS:

```
     <div className="l-grid__col l-grid__col--5 **searchComponent**" data-testid="searchComponent">
                    <Form onSubmit={async () => await fetchData()}>
                    <FormField
                        className="textInput"
                        data-testid="textInput"
                        onChange={e => superOnChange(param, e.target.value)}
                        onBlur={e => {
                            if(param === "number") {
                                validateNumber(e.target.value, setSearchInputError, setSearchInputErrorText);
                                validateNumberLength(e.target.value, setSearchInputError, setSearchInputErrorText, setInputValue);
                            }
                        }


    affixLeft={
     <Select
         data-testid="**dropdown**"
         options={searchOptions()}
         onSelect={e => {
             setParam(e.value);
             superOnChange(e.value, inputValue);
         }}
         hasError = {searchInputError}
         value={inputValue}
     />
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you not access state in the dropdown?

```
 <Select
         data-testid="**dropdown**"
         options={searchOptions()}
         onSelect={e => {
             setParam(e.value);
             superOnChange(e.value, inputValue);
         }}
         value={inputValue}
         error={searchInputErrorText}
     />
```

Comment: I UPDATED QUESTIONS: I tried that @Batman but it only shows a narrow border (Making me think I should rephrase the question to be - how do I create a border css class to wrap around both!)

Answer (score 0):

I would just style the div around the components with errors based on the errors state and use the error message as the value:

```
const [errors, setErrors] = useState([])
function findError(attr) {
  return errors.find(err => err.attr === attr)
}
...
return (
  <div style={{ border: findError("attrOne") ? "1px solid red" : "none" }}>
    <FormField name="attrOne" ... />
    {findError("attrOne") ? <span>{findError("attrOne")</span> : null }}
  </div>

  <div style={{ border: findError("attrTwo") ? "1px solid red" : "none" }}>
    <Select name="attrTwo" ... />
    {findError("attrTwo") ? <span>{findError("attrTwo")</span> : null }}
  </div>
)
```

The error structure would be an object with the field name as the key:

```
[
  { attr: "attrOne", error: "This field is required" },
  { attr: "attrTwo", error: "You must select one option" },
]
```

If the object exists in the errors array that matches the attr name, there is an error on that field, if not, then no. Simple, elegant, and lispy.

Comment: Hi! Sorry @MarkTellez I was in the middle of updating my post when you answered. My needs have changed somewhat, lol. Thank you though.